# Base url redirect ie domain.com to domain2.com but not its sublinks

Tags: .htaccess

We are moving shop.domain.com  to new domains.  Previously we were handling 3 shops via url now we have separate domain for each shop.  So we just need to redirect shop.domain.com to shop1.com by default and we are using other .htaccess rules to redirect old links to shop2 and shop3.  So we just want shop.domain.com  redirect to shop1.com  not its sublinks.  We have written other rules for the same.  Some of the list is below.

```
RewriteRule ^heidelberg/?$ https://shop1.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ludwigshafen/?$ https://shop2.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mannheim/?$ https://shop3.com [L,R=301]
```

But when trying to add the below .htaccess rule to above it stops the above rules. I just need base url redirect to shop1.com  when website is called not its subruls.  For suburls i have separate .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://shop1.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you looking for `RewriteRule ^$` to match a request for the / only?

Comment: what I need is pattern matching dynamic url redirect to static one.